# material not displaying on fresh install of 2.91 since upgrade

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view

Blender was working fine for me a few weeks ago, recently had to replace my ssd, reinstalled blender2.91, and i cant get any materials to display, not in shading, not in uv edit, not in layout/edit mode.

If i open up the default starter scene, select the cube, go to material menu select base colour change it, got to material preview/rendered view, i get a weird grey void where the object should be, if i render it renders as a transparent object amid a black background, same thing if i change the base colour to be an image texture.

Tried 2.90, a few of the 2.8 builds, same issue, checked for updates to my graphics card, there were none.
if i go in to texture paint mode, the image texture is visible, but only in solid viewport rendering
short video of issue here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFJONchZPfg&feature=youtu.be
[image]